# Process a string similar to Chrome's Omnibox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a Google Chrome extension, I want to process a custom string in the same or a similar way to how the Omnibox works.

I think this is easiest to demonstrate with some examples:

```
http://example.org  => We should open the website
example.org         => We should also open the website
example.co.uk/test  => We should also open the website
example             => We should open the default search engine for that term
wp Test             => Given that 'wp' is a shortcut for Wikipedia, we should  
                       open the wiki page for 'Test'
```

Basically what I want to achieve by this is to never have to use the Omnibox again and instead use the VIM-inspired keyboard-only navigation provided by [vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) with the additional benefit of allowing me to navigate to custom pages.

There are now actually two question to it:

- **To what degree does the Chrome API or nasty workarounds allow me to avoid and replicate the logic needed to parse the input?** Can I take advantage of, e.g., an existing list of top-level domains or available URL schemes? Is there even a way to let Chrome do all the work? After all, this stuff needs to be somewhere inside Chrome already, as the Omnibox uses the same algorithm.
- If I am unlucky and I have to implement the logic by myself, **how can I get necessary information like the configured default search engine or the available shortcuts and their associated URL format strings?**

To clarify: I am *not* interested in implementations of the parsing algorithm itself. If the necessary information is available, implementing the algorithm shouldn't be too hard, after all.

Comment: Thats a fun problem to solve... you need to get some passion for programming!

Comment: @Ivan: Actually I am really passionate about programming, but this one I just want to get working fast. I'm trying to hack [another person's extension](https://github.com/philc/vimium) here to be even more useful for me. Unfortunately, I really don't like Javascript, so I thought I'd ask first if somebody has an idea how to solve this more elegantly :)

Comment: regex would be your friend on this one

Comment: @fskreuz: Actually it's less of a parsing problem. It's more like, how to search using the default search engine? How to access search shortcuts? Updated the question to make that a bit more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up completely writing this from scratch: https://github.com/niklasb/vimium/blob/fuzzy/lib/completion.js